# Kextual Healing: How can I remove Kexts that appear on startup?

Tags: macos, terminal, kernel-extensions

On my Mac I have a load of Kexts appearing that read like this (there are 14 or so):

> The system extension "/System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext" was installed improperly and cannot be used...

Now they didn't start appearing after I consciously did anything, and I've read various threads about it elsewhere. I wonder if there is a programming solution here (using Terminal, perhaps) - something that will suppress the kexts? They mostly seem to relate to hp printer drivers, that sort of thing. Stuff I never use.

None of them seem to relate to things in my Login Items in System Preferences.

After discussing this on StackOverflow, I received some advice to run kextutil -n on them:

```
kextutil -n /System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext
```

So I did that, and got this:

> /System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext - dependency 'com.apple.kernel.libkern' not found. Diagnostics for /System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext: Warnings: Personality CFBundleIdentifier differs from containing kext's (not necessarily a mistake, but rarely done): IJ170b...etc.

The message goes on, and ends like this:

> Kext has no executable or compatible version, so it should not declare any OSBundleLibraries.
>   Code Signing Failure: not code signed

Any idea why or what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [Apple Support Communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2814647?start=0&tstart=0) - it addresses your exact problem (specifically, [this response](https://discussions.apple.com/message/13382403#message13382403)).

If you still have issues, prevent the kext from loading by using `sudo` + `kextunload` instead of `kextutil`. For example:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/BJUSBLoad.kext
```

`kextutil` would be appropriate for debugging purposes (corrupted, missing dependencies, deprecated, etc) in the hopes of repairing it. `kextunload` is the tool you are looking for - see the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/man.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/man) for more info on it.

Comment: Thanks so much! That thread & that response solved my problem, so I didn't need to do kextunload. Thanks

Comment: @tardypigeon welcome! glad I could help. Cheers buddy :)